# Inline trigger function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to invoke a function using a trigger without specifically storing it as a named procedure. Is it possible to define the actions right in the trigger definition?

```sql
-- Normally seen structure
CREATE FUNCTION notify() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Nice';
  RETURN NEW;
  END $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER notify_at_insert 
  BEFORE INSERT ON foo
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION notify();
```

```sql
-- Something close to what I want (invalid as is)
CREATE TRIGGER notify_at_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON foo
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE $$
    BEGIN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Nice';
    END $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: That’s not valid syntax for PostgreSQL, not possible

Comment: Thanks to you both.

Comment: Why the downvote? Other databases allow a trigger body (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, SQLite). People coming from other databases, including (if not especially) people with multi-database experience would be surprised by this syntax, and wonder whether they're missing something obvious

Comment: I didn't vote, but at a guess it is because this is explicitly laid out in the official docs page for CREATE TRIGGER. Any answer here is either just repeating that page or is out of date and incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you always have to create a trigger function and call the function in the trigger. Such a function is never inlined. You probably imagine that writing the trigger code into the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement would make the trigger more efficient, but it wouldn't. It is a purely syntactical matter.

Comment: I'm not sure this is about performance. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, SQLite, all allow a trigger body. PostgreSQL syntax will come as a surprise to people that have worked with other databases, especially people that worked with *multiple* databases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When learning something new, most people start with the official documentation. Just copy/paste the examples and start writing your triggers. Using valid syntax, using a trigger function. No matter how different it is, you get something that is valid